# How to remove duplicate data in GridView

Tags: c#, file, gridview, uwp

I have a GridView that is used to display data in the local folder. If the data does not yet exist in the local folder, I want it to copy from the "uu file" in the solution package. Whereas, if it is already in the local folder, it will immediately get data from the local folder.

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Book> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Book>();    
StorageFolder _folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync("UU pdf");
    _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync(direktori.Direktori);
    _folder = await _folder.GetFolderAsync(direktori.Name);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> _files = await _folder.GetFilesAsync(); //which returns List<StorageFile>

    StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFolder localFolder1 = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("FileUU", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    ((App)(App.Current)).DirectoriName = direktori.Direktori;
    StorageFolder localFolder2 = await localFolder1.CreateFolderAsync(((App)(App.Current)).DirectoriName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    ((App)(App.Current)).DirektoriYear = direktori.Name;
    StorageFolder localFolder3 = await localFolder2.CreateFolderAsync(((App)(App.Current)).DirektoriYear, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    foreach (StorageFile file in _files)
    {
        if (!CheckFileExists(file.Name))    
        {
            try
            {
                        await file.CopyAsync(localFolder3);
                }
                catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> _filesC = await localFolder3.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile fileC in _filesC)
    {
        string name = @"SELECT filename from undangundang where identifier='" + fileC.DisplayName.Replace("_", " ").ToUpper() + "'";
            var nameQuery = objConnUpdate.Prepare(name);
            nameQuery.Step();
            Book buku = new Book();
            string name1 = nameQuery[0].ToString().Replace("_", " ");
            buku.Name = name1;
            datasource.Add(buku);
    }
    itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
```

Book.cs

```
public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Direktori { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a problem, that is, the data is displayed in the GridView always repeats as shown below:
[image: duplicate data on gridview]

How do I handle it?

Comment: Have you checked the `datasource`. Is the repeated data the in the source ?

Comment: I found you get data source from date base with the name file's name. Could you tell why do this ?

Comment: From the screenshot, these four data are not repeated.

Comment: the data is only 2 file: "uu no 01 th 2009 - ..." and "uu no 2 th 2009 - ....". And I have checked in the local package that the file is only 2

Comment: file's name is using for check the file is exists on local package or not

Comment: Your data comes from db file. You should check if the database contains duplicate data.

Comment: I have checked the database and the results are only 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193682/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-rose).

Comment: I have checked your code, if you have two files in the local folder, then it will query the database twice in the foreach block.

Comment: How to fix that?

Comment: This is based on your requirement, why you need to  query the database with each file's name.  and please tell  more about  `identifier` key.

Comment: I need a query to check whether the file is in the database and folder. If it is not in the database, the file will be deleted, and if it is not in the file, the data in the database will be deleted. The identifier functions to check whether the file name is the same as the identifier

Comment: I'm confuse why database contains two items(xxxx and xxxx.pdf) match each file?

Comment: the query is contain one item:  string name = @"SELECT filename from undangundang where identifier='" + fileC.DisplayName.Replace("_", " ").ToUpper() + "'";

Comment: The item contains .pdf extension name ?

Comment: yes, but in identifier not contains .pdf extension

Comment: Where the .pdf extension comes from?

Comment: in the file name

Comment: Have you updated `datasource` elsewhere?

Comment: yes, I have updated

Comment: Could you  share [mcve]?

Comment: I have edited the code in my post above

Comment: You just add the `Book` class which has nothing to do with duplicate data.